# secured dataservices in wso2 creating lot of ldap connections

Tags: ldap, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

we have secured our dataservices in wso2 using LDAPS..
LDAPS is our primary user store..
Since we have lot of dataservices and all dataservices are secured using LDAPS ;its creating an overhead in LDAPS.
How to overcome this?

Is there a way to secure dataservices using diffeernt mechanims rather than primary user store? Any other authentication will do ; like a basic auth which hits only wso2 DB?how to configure this? Primary store has to stay as LDAPS since lot of other things are around LDAPS..B
Is there a way to configure connetion cachine/pooling against LDAPS? its a secure LDAP and not sure connection pooling works against LDAPS

Comment: You can configure a secondary user store. But this needs to have the respective users to validate them when invoking the secured DSS

Comment: thats a good idea..but how do i tell in security policy that it should be validated against the secondary data store?any examples plz